# Protractor: Save url as string for later redirect

Tags: angularjs, protractor

How can I save the current URL as a String? I want to navigate somewhere else and later navigate back to the saved URL. I dont want to use `browser.navigate().back()` for this.

When I for example do

```
var urlString;

browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
    urlString = url;
});

....redirecting...navigating...


browser.waitForAngular();
browser.get(urlString); // get back to beginning URL
```

it fails because the promise has not been fullfilled and `urlString` is `undefined`

Is there a possiblity to do this without breaking the test-flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Put you test inside a describe.
2. Add a before each to save the url.
3. Run the test, the value should be resolved.

```js
describe('my test', function() {
  var urlString;

  beforeEach(function() {
    browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
      urlString = url;
    });
  });

  it('should go and come back', function() {
    // Here the value has already been resolved.
    ....redirecting...navigating...

    browser.waitForAngular();
    browser.get(urlString); // get back to beginning URL
  });
})
```

... or you can put all of your test inside the `then` of the `getCurrentUrl()`

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate to new a URL in the promise itself:

```
browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(cUrl){
   browser.get(cUrl.replace('a','b'));
})
```